# How to drag ImageView into CollectionView in Swift and CollectionView Item into ImageView like tinder App profile edit

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm newbie in iOS and I don't know how to do it, I want to Implement tinder like profile edit animation.

for example,

I can drag image into to other `UIImageView` or `UICollectionView` and Collection Item into Main `UIImageView`.

I have implement `LongGestureListener` of `UICollectionView` But I can only drag and drop item between UICollectionView Items.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe a video for those of us that do t use Tinder but my guess is a percent driven transition or just a cgrect intersects with both rects converted to the same coordinates system and then animate into that rect

Comment: i have found best solution thanks alll

Answer (score 1):

**for swift 4.2**

- images come from prev controller

  ```
            import UIKit
            private let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
            class MyRoomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
                var images: [UIImage] = []
                var screenSize: CGRect!
                var screenWidth: CGFloat!
                fileprivate var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

                override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()

                    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

                    screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
                    screenWidth = screenSize.width - 6

                    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
                    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 1, bottom: 10, right: 1)
                    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth / 3, height: screenWidth / 3)
                    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.5
                    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.5
                    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout

                    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
                    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
                }

                override func numberOfSections(in _: UICollectionView) -> Int {
                    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
                    return 1
                }

                override func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
                    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
                    return images.count
                }

                override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RoomCollectionViewCell

                    cell.img.image = images[indexPath.row]

                    return cell
                }

                override func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt _: IndexPath) -> Bool {
                    return true
                }

                override func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
                {
                    // print("Starting Index: \(sourceIndexPath.item)")
                    // print("Ending Index: \(destinationIndexPath.item)")
                    let temp = images[sourceIndexPath.item]
                    images.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
                    images.insert(temp, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
                    collectionView.reloadData()
                }

                @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
                    switch gesture.state {
                    case .began:
                        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else {
                            break
                        }
                        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
                    case .changed:
                        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
                    case .ended:
                        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
                    default:
                        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
                    }
                }

                @IBAction func arrangeIt(_: Any) {
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "videosegue", sender: self)
                }

                override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender _: Any?) {
                    let dest = segue.destination as! VideoMakerViewController
                    dest.images = images
                }
            }
  ```